# Can't figure out why my function is not treating a passed value as needed

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's my code:

```
carats <- pull(diamonds %>% distinct(carat) %>% arrange(carat))

get_price_by_category <- function(dataset, x, y) {
    print(c(x, typeof(x)))
    dataset %>% filter(carat == x) %>% print()
}

carats %>% walk(get_price_by_category, dataset = diamonds, y= "price")
```

When I run it, I get these results:

```
[1] "0.2"    "double"
# A tibble: 0 x 10
# … with 10 variables: carat <dbl>, cut <ord>, color <ord>, clarity <ord>,
#   depth <dbl>, table <dbl>, price <int>, x <dbl>, y <dbl>, z <dbl>
[1] "0.21"   "double"
# A tibble: 0 x 10
# … with 10 variables: carat <dbl>, cut <ord>, color <ord>, clarity <ord>,
#   depth <dbl>, table <dbl>, price <int>, x <dbl>, y <dbl>, z <dbl>
[1] "0.22"   "double"
# A tibble: 0 x 10
# … with 10 variables: carat <dbl>, cut <ord>, color <ord>, clarity <ord>,
#   depth <dbl>, table <dbl>, price <int>, x <dbl>, y <dbl>, z <dbl>
[1] "0.23"   "double"
# A tibble: 0 x 10
# … with 10 variables: carat <dbl>, cut <ord>, color <ord>, clarity <ord>,
#   depth <dbl>, table <dbl>, price <int>, x <dbl>, y <dbl>, z <dbl>
...
```

So, obviously, my function recognizes the value being passed, and the variable type is equivalent to the type of the column it's being filtered on. But, just as obviously, it's not treating it as needed in the filter(carat == x) function.

If I change the code by changing walk() to a for() loop and passing the value of carat explicitly:

```
carats <- pull(diamonds %>% distinct(carat) %>% arrange(carat))

get_price_by_category <- function(dataset, x, y) {
    print(c(x, typeof(x)))
    dataset %>% filter(carat == x) %>% print()
}

for (c in carats) {
    get_price_by_category(diamonds, c, y= "price")
}
```

the results are the same.

If, however, I leave the for() loop, but change the code in my function to reference c instead of x (even when I leave it as x in the parameter list), I get the desired result:

```
carats <- pull(diamonds %>% distinct(carat) %>% arrange(carat))

get_price_by_category <- function(dataset, x, y) {
    print(c(c, typeof(c)))
    dataset %>% filter(carat == c) %>% print()
}

for (c in carats) {
    get_price_by_category(diamonds, c, y= "price")
}
```

Result:

```
[1] "0.2"    "double"
# A tibble: 12 x 10
   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   0.2 Premium   E     SI2      60.2    62   345  3.79  3.75  2.27
 2   0.2 Premium   E     VS2      59.8    62   367  3.79  3.77  2.26
 3   0.2 Premium   E     VS2      59      60   367  3.81  3.78  2.24
 4   0.2 Premium   E     VS2      61.1    59   367  3.81  3.78  2.32
 5   0.2 Premium   E     VS2      59.7    62   367  3.84  3.8   2.28
 6   0.2 Ideal     E     VS2      59.7    55   367  3.86  3.84  2.3 
 7   0.2 Premium   F     VS2      62.6    59   367  3.73  3.71  2.33
 8   0.2 Ideal     D     VS2      61.5    57   367  3.81  3.77  2.33
 9   0.2 Very Good E     VS2      63.4    59   367  3.74  3.71  2.36
10   0.2 Ideal     E     VS2      62.2    57   367  3.76  3.73  2.33
11   0.2 Premium   D     VS2      62.3    60   367  3.73  3.68  2.31
12   0.2 Premium   D     VS2      61.7    60   367  3.77  3.72  2.31
[1] "0.21"   "double"
# A tibble: 9 x 10
  carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
  <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
2  0.21 Very Good E     VS2      63.2    54   386  3.82  3.78  2.4 
3  0.21 Premium   E     VS2      60.5    59   386  3.87  3.83  2.33
4  0.21 Premium   E     VS2      59.6    56   386  3.93  3.89  2.33
5  0.21 Premium   D     VS2      61.6    59   386  3.82  3.78  2.34
6  0.21 Premium   D     VS2      60.6    60   386  3.85  3.81  2.32
7  0.21 Premium   D     VS2      59.1    62   386  3.89  3.86  2.29
8  0.21 Premium   D     VS2      58.3    59   386  3.96  3.93  2.3 
9  0.21 Premium   E     SI2      61.9    56   394  3.84  3.82  2.37
...
```

So the fact that I can leave it as x in the parameter list and still get the desired result as long as I reference it as c in the actual function code makes me realize that somehow the value in my call is not being passed to my function as I'm expecting it to be. But I cannot figure out why this doesn't work, or what I need to do to get it to work.

Comment: Side note: I recommend against naming a variable `c` (or the same as common variables in R). You can get away with it usually (R is generally good at differentiating your intention for a *variable* named `c` versus the function named `c`), but it can make reading/troubleshooting your code rather difficult

Comment: Yeah, I've been defaulting to a standard of using the first letter in my data vector, but any time that's a letter that I know has a special meaning in R, I realize it's bad practice. I need to quit being lazy and start being more thoughtful about my variable names - it would have prevented me from struggling with this issue, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here, and while you're seeing problem 2, I think you should really look at problem 1 so that you are not bitten by another bug.

1. Doing *equality* tests with floating point on digital computers is unfortunately **fundamentally flawed** (IEEE-754, [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f)). The only assurance you have of matching a floating-point value is to looking "around it" with tolerance (a test of *inequality*), such as `abs(carat-0.2) < 1e-8`. (You can get away with it for some comparisons, but you won't really know when it'll bite you until something weird happens and you dig in deep.) To do this, you should likely know something about the data itself so that your choice of `1e-8` is correctly informed.
2. `x` is seen as `dataset$x`, not the function argument ... try using an argument name that is not in the dataset.

   ```r
   get_price_by_category <- function(dataset, a, b, tol = 1e-8) {
       print(c(x, typeof(x)))
       dataset %>% filter(abs(carat - a) < tol) %>% print()
   }
   carats %>% head(n=2) %>% walk(get_price_by_category, dataset = diamonds, b = "price")
   # [1] "0.2"    "double"
   # # A tibble: 12 x 10
   #    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
   #    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
   #  1   0.2 Premium   E     SI2      60.2    62   345  3.79  3.75  2.27
   #  2   0.2 Premium   E     VS2      59.8    62   367  3.79  3.77  2.26
   #  3   0.2 Premium   E     VS2      59      60   367  3.81  3.78  2.24
   #  4   0.2 Premium   E     VS2      61.1    59   367  3.81  3.78  2.32
   #  5   0.2 Premium   E     VS2      59.7    62   367  3.84  3.8   2.28
   #  6   0.2 Ideal     E     VS2      59.7    55   367  3.86  3.84  2.3 
   #  7   0.2 Premium   F     VS2      62.6    59   367  3.73  3.71  2.33
   #  8   0.2 Ideal     D     VS2      61.5    57   367  3.81  3.77  2.33
   #  9   0.2 Very Good E     VS2      63.4    59   367  3.74  3.71  2.36
   # 10   0.2 Ideal     E     VS2      62.2    57   367  3.76  3.73  2.33
   # 11   0.2 Premium   D     VS2      62.3    60   367  3.73  3.68  2.31
   # 12   0.2 Premium   D     VS2      61.7    60   367  3.77  3.72  2.31
   # [1] "0.2"    "double"
   # # A tibble: 9 x 10
   #   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
   #   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
   # 1  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
   # 2  0.21 Very Good E     VS2      63.2    54   386  3.82  3.78  2.4 
   # 3  0.21 Premium   E     VS2      60.5    59   386  3.87  3.83  2.33
   # 4  0.21 Premium   E     VS2      59.6    56   386  3.93  3.89  2.33
   # 5  0.21 Premium   D     VS2      61.6    59   386  3.82  3.78  2.34
   # 6  0.21 Premium   D     VS2      60.6    60   386  3.85  3.81  2.32
   # 7  0.21 Premium   D     VS2      59.1    62   386  3.89  3.86  2.29
   # 8  0.21 Premium   D     VS2      58.3    59   386  3.96  3.93  2.3 
   # 9  0.21 Premium   E     SI2      61.9    56   394  3.84  3.82  2.37
   ```

**N.B.** I'll say it again: the choice of `tol`erance is critical to the logical accuracy of this function. If you're dealing with a units that are typically in the 1s or 1000s with 8 or fewer significant digits, then `1e-8` is fine. If you're dealing with high-precision numbers, you may need to get closer to `.Machine$double.eps` (which, on my 64-bit machine, is `2.22e-16`, see [`?.Machine`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/.Machine) for details about the components of this variable). I have no reason to *not* default to that, but this is why I said *"choice of 1e-8 is correctly informed"* -- only you know your data, if there is no practical difference beyond 1/1000ths, then you can use `tol=1e-3`.

Comment: r2evans, thanks. I had actually figured out problem #2 before I posted my answer above, but I'd forgotten about the dangers of using == versus the equality function.

I’m going to leave my answer up as well, but I’m giving you the check mark because you saw it well before I did.

Thanks again, appreciate the help.

Comment: The floating-point thing is an easy one to lose sight of, and frankly I think most data-scientists need to be reminded of it periodically, even some CS-minded people too. It has bitten me before -- matching part time, failing part time -- so I don't miss opportunities to "soap box" it a little. Hope it wasn't preach-y. :-)